# Why is PHP $_SESSION changing token variable?

Tags: php, session, session-variables

I've got a really weird problem.

This is my file:

```
<?php

session_start();

echo $_SESSION['token']; // should print previous token

echo "<br/>";    

$_SESSION['token'] = md5(uniqid()); // set new token

echo $_SESSION['token']; // new token which should carry through on page load, but doesn't

?>
```

Really simple!

The first echo statement should print the token set on the previous page load. But for some weird reason which I can't figure out, is that it prints an entirely different token!

Thanks a lot for any pointers.

Comment: Do you have any mod_rewrite rules pointing to this script by chance?

Comment: is the cookie actualy being created? are there files within your configured session.save_path? Edit: your script is functioning, so look for configuration issues.

Comment: @DanGrossman - Aha! yes it is something to do with rewrite rules (I'm using nginx). When I remove the rules and access the file directly it is fine. Any idea why this would be?

Comment: Every time you request a webpage your browser makes a second request for `/favicon.ico`... are you also mapping that request to this script?

Comment: @DanGrossman - you're absolutely right. That was the problem. a request to favicon.ico was being re-written to my frame.php which in turn was triggering a new token. I don't think I ever would have worked that one out. Please post the answer so I can accept.

Comment: @Emmanuel Cool, I've made it an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every time you request a webpage your browser makes a second request for `/favicon.ico`. If you have a rewrite rule mapping those requests to this script as well, that'd be changing your tokens.